# Vue - splicing a positioned element from an array will apply its offset to next index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, vue.js

I'm quite new to Vue and have been working on a small project that uses a lot of positioned objects on the screen. I've found that slicing an index from my model will cause its positioning to be applied to the next index, resetting its own.

The example below is related (demonstrates similar unexpected behaviour), but not entirely my issue - being the offset transferring to the next index.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [0, 1, 2, 3]
  },
  methods: {
    take: function(i) {
      var item = $(i.target).closest('.sort').index();
      this.items.splice(item, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.sort {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}
.sort:nth-child(1) {
  top: 54px;
  left: 140px;
}
.sort:nth-child(2) {
  top: 155px;
  left: 230px;
}
.sort:nth-child(3) {
  top: 226px;
  left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="sort" v-for="item in items">
    {{ item }}

    <span class="remove" v-on:click="take">x</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The expected behaviour is for the items to stay positioned as they were until they're deleted themselves. My current solution is to take a copy of the next index's styles and apply them again. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you referencing the displayed number changing or the actual position of element within viewport?

Comment: My question is regarding why the actual positions of each element in the viewport are changing.

Comment: The positions of the elements in the viewport do not change at stacksnippets, here.

Comment: @kyle let me know your feedback on the answer below? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `splice` out an item from `items` it is removed from the DOM-binded array. Because you are using `nth-child(1)` to `nth-child(3)` the *positions are shifted* as a deleted element shifts the remaining  up.

So I have some suggestions for you:

1. Give that the positions of each element is specific, so why not put it in the data like `{item: 0, class: 'zero'}` for example - and there is a change in markup:

   ```
   <div v-bind:class="['sort', item.class]" v-for="item in items">
        {{ item.item }} <span class="remove" v-on:click="take(item)">x</span>
   </div>
   ```
2. Instead of calculating `index` like you have done, its better to pass `item` as an argument as index can vary if you apply ordering/filtering.
3. Still the positions will not be correct- its better to keep `app` as `relative` and apply `absolute` for all of the `sort` classes.

See demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      item: 0,
      class: 'zero'
    }, {
      item: 1,
      class: 'one'
    }, {
      item: 2,
      class: 'two'
    }, {
      item: 3,
      class: 'three'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    take: function(item) {
      this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
#app {
  position: relative;
}
.sort {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
}
.remove {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sort.zero {
  top: 54px;
  left: 140px;
}
.sort.one {
  top: 155px;
  left: 230px;
}
.sort.two {
  top: 226px;
  left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-bind:class="['sort', item.class]" v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.item }} <span class="remove" v-on:click="take(item)">x</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the response! I appreciate the suggestions, means a lot as a newcomer to Vue. Your solution makes sense, though I was having troubles without the nth-child styles as well. Nevertheless, your solution and suggestions have helped resolve any issues I had regarding this :)